# How to generate request using JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, httprequest

well I'm doing a web application, which processes a file after it's done uploading and I want somehow the user to to be able to get some info about the progress. Now I was thinking of creating a jsp progress page, which would sleep for 5 seconds, then generate a request and supply it with the filename that we want to know the progress of. So how do I do this, or is there a better way? Maybe JavaScript can do the desired actions? So what would you guys suggest? Thanks.

Comment: I think this would be done better using AJAX (which will need a servlet in the server side).

Comment: @SJuan76 you can't upload files using ajax.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Search for a jQuery component that handles file uploading and *pretty* presentation of the file upload. Just to cite an example, I used [blueimp jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) component and worked like a charm.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks a lot, I might use it for the upload, though right now I'm thinking of showing the user some text about the processing of the uploaded file

Answer (score 1):

You need to poll the server using ajax.  If you're using Java, the Apache FileUpload library has an interface called [ProgressListener](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-monitor-the-progress-of-a-file-upload-to-a-servlet.html?page=2), which you implement to determine the upload's progress.  You can track percentage received or just mark a file complete when it's complete.  On the client side, you check the progress every few seconds until you see it's finished.  Also, if you want your user to appear to remain on the same page, try setting the target attribute of your form to the id of a 0x0 iframe on submit.

If you decide to code the javascript, a simple polling function might look like this:

```
function poll(uploadId) {
    $.ajax({
         url: '/path/to/upload/status/servlet',
         type: 'POST',
         data: 'id=' uploadId,
         dataType: 'json',
         timeout: 10000,
         error: function(err){
             // handle error
         },
         success: function(data) {
             var status = data["status"];

             if (status == 'finished') 
             {
                 // completed upload logic
             }
             else
             {
                 setTimeout(function() {
                     poll(uploadId);
                 }, pollingIntervalInMillis);               
             }
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: "On the client side, you check the progress every few seconds until you see it's finished" - this is what I'm asking for, how do I do this?

Comment: @ArturasM again, jQuery plugins already handle this for you (apart of other functionalities). Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but I need the progress not for the file upload but for the progress of my app processing the uploaded file? what kind of plugins can do that?

Comment: @ArturasM if you upload and process the file in a same call, then the plugin will handle this for you since the upload is completed **only** when the server sends a response to the file upload request. If it's a separate process, then there are other jQuery plugins that handle a progress bar for server operations.

Answer (score 0):

Poll the server (requires a progress API) periodically (via javascript) for the processing status and update the page accordingly when you get a positive result.

Comment: Yeah, well that's exactly what I'm asking you, how do I do that?